# control speed of sound xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, slider, slowdown

I'm wondering whether it's possible to slow down a sound in xcode. I mean I'll add some .mp3 file in my supporting files in xcode and I'll create app which will be able to speed it up or slow down. For example with slider. Is it even possible? If yes, could anyone help me with some idea? Thanks

Comment: For what platform, `iOS` or `OS X`?

Comment: just for clarity, you want to slow down playback rate, not slow down the speed of sound, correct?  As speed of sound is dependent upon the medium the sound wave is passing through.

Comment: for iOS and I want to slow down/speed up speed of sound. Like it's 120bpm and I want to make it 100bpm or 150bpm

Answer (score 2):

AVAudioPlayer has a rate property which should be able to help you accomplish your goal.
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

> The audio player’s playback rate. @property float rate
>
> Discussion
>
> This property’s default value of 1.0 provides normal playback rate.
>   The available range is from 0.5 for half-speed playback through 2.0
>   for double-speed playback.
>
> To set an audio player’s playback rate, you must first enable rate
>   adjustment as described in the enableRate property description.

I also found a good SO post on the AVAudioPlayer's rate:
[AVAudioPlayer rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131631/avaudioplayer-rate)

Seems like as you'd mentioned you could set a slider with values from 0.5 to 2.0 and on valuechanged modify the audio players rate by using

```
- (IBAction)changeValue:(UISlider *)sender
{
    //made up assumed ivar names
    if ([_audioPlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnableRate:)])
        _audioPlayer.enableRate = YES;
    if ([_audioPlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setRate:)])
        _audioPlayer.rate = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slideValue];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this? where should I put my mp3 sound. I imageine it that there will be button which will start playing sound and there will be also slider which would be able to speed up/slow down the sound. I know how to code this button but how can I conect it to slider?

Answer (score 0):

Playing PCM audio at a faster or slower rate than its sample rate changes its pitch and also introduces considerable artefacts. If you're OK with this,  the approach you would use is to decode the MP3 into PCM audio and then use [Direct Digital Synthesis Oscillator](http://www.electricdruid.net/index.php?page=info.dds) to control the playback rate.

If you want to maintain pitch but change speed, you need a audio time-stretching algorithm.

[Dirac3](http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac/) from [DSP Dimension](http://www.dspdimension.com) is a commercial product that can do it, and which is available for licensing for use in iOS application.  Other commercial solutions exist.

DSP Dimension's [blog](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/) provides a helpful tutorial on the basics of how to implement pitch-shifting 
using a FFT.   Time stretching is essentially the same process.  However, there's a fair bit of secret sauce in the DIRAC plug-in they don't tell you about.

Be warned that unless you're a Electronics engineering, physics or maths graduate, you'll probably it tough going to fill in the blanks.